# How to return a BOOL with asynchronous request in a method? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

I've a server where I request some data.

I'm checking if an image with certain name exists on it and I need to return a BOOL value (YES or NO), but I don't know how to do it, because asynchronous request calls a callback when it's finished, so when it finishes method has finished long time ago and it don't return BOOL value and I don't use synchronous request because it blocks main thread.

Here's my code (I know it's wrong, but I write it anyway to show an example of what I wanna do, cause my english is not so well):

```
- (BOOL)imageDoesExistsOnTheServer:(NSString *)imageName {
    BOOL exists;

    NSString * query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"request=IMAGE&imageName=%@", imageName];

    DREasyURLRequest * imageExistsRequest = [[DREasyURLRequest alloc] initForSendDataToServerWithURLString:@"http://xxxxx.xxxxx/file.php" query:query];

    [imageExistsRequest sendAsynchronouslyWithCompletionForStringAsResponse:^(NSString *receivedResponse) {
        if ([receivedResponse isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            __block BOOL exists = YES;
        } else {
            __block BOOL exists = NO;
        }
    }];

    return exists;
}
```

(DREasyURLRequest is a subclass of NSMutableURLRequest I've created to save some code, but sendAsynchronouslyWithCompletionForStringAsResponse: does absolutely the same as asynchronous NSMutableURLRequest method.

Can you guys help me?

P.D: I know, this code looks SO bad hahaha but I don't have idea about what to do...

Comment: Your code can't be sync and async in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block is not called by your code, so you cannot use `return` to provide anything to your code.  Instead, stop thinking about return values, and start thinking about behaviour.  You want something to happen when you get a positive response, and you want something to happen when you get a negative response.  So write methods for each of these behaviours, and call them at the appropriate places in your blocks.

Comment: OMG it's just true! Reading your question, I've realized it's really stupid to create that method, cause I've a completion block that handles all uploading stuff when a response is received. THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

Comment: This answer was helpful to me. Writing and consuming asynchronous code is a mindset change for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return values like this. The function won't wait until the asynchronous execution of the block is done. The idiomatic pattern for handling situations like this is keeping the asynchronous nature of the control flow and implementing your callback logic accordingly. For example, you could use delegation or pass in another block which would notify you whether the image exists:

```
- (BOOL)imageDoesExistsOnTheServer:(NSString *)imageName completion:(void ^(BOOL exists)compl {
    // etc.
    [imageExistsRequest sendAsynchronouslyWithCompletionForStringAsResponse:^(NSString *receivedResponse) {
    if ([receivedResponse isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        compl(YES);
    } else {
        compl(NO);
    }
}];
```

and call it like this:

```
[self imageDoesExistOnTheServer:@"Foo.png" completion:^(BOOL exists) {
    if (exists) {
        // exists
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, but the answer is simpler than it. Jim has helped me first, so accepted answer is for him, but thank you so much too ;)