# Obj-C: __block variable not retaining data

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I think I might have an async problem going on here, which bites cause I thought I had solved it. Anyway, I am making a bunch of web service calls like so:

```
//get the client data
__block NSArray* arrClientPAs;
[dataManager getJSONData:strWebService withBlock:^(id results, NSError* error) {            
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Getting Client Data Error!" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Okay", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        arrClientPAs = results;
    }
 }];
```

and getJSONData is like so:

```
- (void) getJSONData : (NSString*) strQuery withBlock:(void (^)(id, NSError *))completion {
    NSDictionary* dictNetworkStatus = [networkManager checkNetworkConnectivity];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [[dictNetworkStatus objectForKey:@"Status"] intValue];

    if (networkStatus != NotReachable) {
        //set up the url for webservice
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:strQuery];
        NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        //set up the url connection
        __block id results;
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
         ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* jsonData, NSError* error) {
             if (error) {
                 completion(nil, error);
                 return;
             }

            results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error]; 
            completion(results, nil);
         }];            
    } else {
        //not connected to a network - data is going to have to come from coredata
    }
}
```

In the first block, if I log arrClientData I can see the data that I am expecting but when I log arrClientData after it it is nil. I was following this SO thread - [How to return a BOOL with asynchronous request in a method? (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161257/how-to-return-a-bool-with-asynchronous-request-in-a-method-objective-c) and a couple of others.

Obviously I am trying to get the data after the async call is made. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies, I think, in what "asynchronous" means. Here's a diagram:

```
Step One
__block result;
Step Two - do something asynchonous, including e.g. setting result
Step Three
```

What order do things happen in here? Step Three happens *before* Step Two gets finished. *That* is what asynchronous means: it means, "go right on with *this* code, don't wait for the asynchronous stuff to finish." So at the time Step Three happens, the `result` variable has not yet been set to anything.

So, you are just misleading the heck out of yourself with your `__block result`. `__block` or no `__block`, there is no way you are going to find out out what the `result` is *afterwards*, because there is no "afterwards". Your code has completed before your `__block result` is even set. That is why asynchronous code uses a callback (eg. your `completion` block) which *does* run afterwards, because it is sequentially part of (appended to) the asynchronous code. You can hand your result *downwards* through the callback, but you cannot usefully set it *upwards* from within the block and expect to retrieve it later.

So, your overall structure is like this:

```
__block NSArray* arrClientPAs; // it's nil
[call getJSONdata] = step one
     [call sendAsynchronousRequest]
          do the block _asynchronously_ = step two, tries to set arrClientPAs somehow
step three! This happens _before_ step two, ...
... and this entire method ends and is torn down ...
... and arrClientPAs is still nil!
```

I repeat: you cannot pass any information UP out of an asynchronous block. You can only go DOWN. You need your asynchronous block to call some method of some *independently persistent object* to hand it your result and tell it to use that result (and do it carefully, on the main thread, or you will cause havoc). You cannot use *any* automatic variable for this purpose, such as your declared NSArray variable `arrClientPAs`; there is no automatic scope any more, the method is over, the automatic variable is gone, there is no more code to run.

Comment: I get what async means, I'm not grokking how to resolve it. : D

Comment: Hang in there, I'm still refining my answer (might or might not get more useful) :))))

Comment: @Pruitlgoe Instead of assigning the variable to a block variable you should send a message to the object to store the data (when the task is finished).

Comment: Yes, well put, @AminNegm-Awad - and/or do something with it in the `completion` handler.

Comment: Yes, or to sum it up: Do what you do with arrClientPAs behind (not: after) the block simply inside the block.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought I was doing, passing it downwards - aren't I calling completion block within the completionHandler of NSURLConnection? And doesn't that get called after the results are returned?

Comment: No, because the same thing is true for your `[dataManager getJSONData:strWebService withBlock:^(id results, NSError* error) {` call. You make that call and your code there goes right on and finishes. End of story! You can't communicate back by setting the `__block arrClientPAs` from within the block. That setting happens _later_ - it is asynchronous! The method in which you call `getJSONData` is over, done, dead, gone, finished. It is an ex-method! It has gone to meet its maker. It is pushing up daisies. :)))

Comment: The thread should wait in step 3 until there is some error or arrClientPAs.

Comment: @AaronBrager Done, but I don't know if it will be visible except on Mac OS X machine...

Comment: @matt - just getting back to this many hours later, I think I understand the problem as you and CRD outlined it. Not sure if you were doing a Python tribute but hey, my method is not dead, it's just resting. : )

Comment: @PruitIgoe look carefully at what @Amin said: your completion handler needs to send a message to some _persistent object_ to store the data. This could, for example, be the data manager or the original object that started this whole process (the one that called the data manager in the first place). `arrClientPAs` could be an _instance variable_ (and the method might simply be the setter for that instance variable).

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the 'error 'variable after call:

```
results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

If 'error' isn't nil there is a problem with data which you get in your completion block.

Comment: The app initially calls this method 8 times and error is nil for all 8. Plus, I can see the correct data, it's just not passing it out of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing styles and confusing the purpose of `__block`.

**Note**: When you call a method that will be executed asynchronously you are creating a new *execution path* which will be executed at some point in the future (which includes immediately) on *some* thread.

In your `getJSONData` method you use a `__block` qualified variable, `results`, when you should not. The variable is only required within the block and should be declared there:

```
//set up the url connection
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* jsonData, NSError* error)
 {
     if (error) {
         completion(nil, error);
         return;
     }

     id results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error]; 
     completion(results, nil);
 }];
```

Declaring the variable outside of the block and adding `__block` just adds pointless complexity. After the call to `sendAsynchronousRequest`, returns before the request has been performed, the value of `results` would **not** be the value assigned in the block. The call to the completion block is performed on a different execution path and probably will not even be executed until after the call to `getJSONData` has returned.

However what is correct about your `getJSONData` method is its model - it takes a completion block which `sendAsynchronousRequest`'s own completion handler will call. This is what is incorrect about your call to `getJSONData` - the completion block you pass does *not* pass on the results to another block or pass them to some object, but instead assigns them a local variable, `arrClientPAs`, declared before the call. This is the same situation as described above for `getJSONData` and will fail for the same reasons - it is not the `arrClientPAs` fails to "retain the data" but that you are reading it on in the current execution path *before* another execution path has written any data to it.

You can address this problem the same way `getJSONData` does - the enclosing method (not included in your question) can take a completion block (code entered directly into answer, expect typos!):

```
- (void) getTheClientData: ... completionHandler:(void (^)(id))handler
{
   ...
   //get the client data
   [dataManager getJSONData:strWebService withBlock:^(id results, NSError* error) {            
       if (error) {
           UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Getting Client Data Error!" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Okay", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
           [alert show];
       } else {
           handler(results); // "return" the result to the handler
       }
    }];
```

There is another approach. **If and only if** `getClientData` is not executing on the main thread and you wish its behaviour to be synchronous and to return the result of the request then you can issue a `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` instead of an asynchronous one. This will block the thread `getClientData` is executing on until the request completes.

In general if you have an asynchronous method which you cannot replace by a synchronous one but require synchronous behaviour you can use *semaphores* to block your current thread until the asynchronous call completes. For an example of how to do this see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166316/return-nsstring-which-is-set-from-inside-a-block/16166778#16166778).

HTH